# How do I pass data between Electron and a native Node.js module (nan)?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have this [code](https://github.com/tree-sitter/node-tree-sitter/blob/d10867d92887c9a40eeacf611a54d26c93927f1a/src/node.cc#L33-L38) that implements Node bindings for a C library using [nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan). It creates a buffer that it uses to pass data from JavaScript to C:

```cpp
static inline void setup_transfer_buffer(uint32_t node_count) {
  uint32_t new_length = node_count * FIELD_COUNT_PER_NODE;
  if (new_length > transfer_buffer_length) {
    if (transfer_buffer) {
      free(transfer_buffer);
    }
    transfer_buffer_length = new_length;
    transfer_buffer = static_cast<uint32_t *>(malloc(transfer_buffer_length * sizeof(uint32_t)));

    #if (V8_MAJOR_VERSION < 8 || (V8_MAJOR_VERSION == 8 && V8_MINOR_VERSION < 4) || (V8_MAJOR_VERSION == 8 && NODE_RUNTIME_ELECTRON))
      auto js_transfer_buffer = ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), transfer_buffer, transfer_buffer_length * sizeof(uint32_t));
    #else
      auto backing_store = ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore(transfer_buffer, transfer_buffer_length * sizeof(uint32_t), BackingStore::EmptyDeleter, nullptr);
      auto js_transfer_buffer = ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), std::move(backing_store));
    #endif

    Nan::Set(
      Nan::New(module_exports),
      Nan::New("nodeTransferArray").ToLocalChecked(),
      Uint32Array::New(js_transfer_buffer, 0, transfer_buffer_length)
    );
  }
}

Local<Value> GetMarshalNode(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &info, const Tree *tree, TSNode node) {
  const auto &cache_entry = tree->cached_nodes_.find(node.id);
  if (cache_entry == tree->cached_nodes_.end()) {
    setup_transfer_buffer(1);
    uint32_t *p = transfer_buffer;
    MarshalNodeId(node.id, p);
    p += 2;
    *(p++) = node.context[0];
    *(p++) = node.context[1];
    *(p++) = node.context[2];
    *(p++) = node.context[3];
    if (node.id) {
      return Nan::New(ts_node_symbol(node));
    }
  } else {
    return Nan::New(cache_entry->second->node);
  }
  return Nan::Null();
}

void MarshalNode(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &info, const Tree *tree, TSNode node) {
  info.GetReturnValue().Set(GetMarshalNode(info, tree, node));
}

static void FirstNamedChildForIndex(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &info) {
  const Tree *tree = Tree::UnwrapTree(info[0]);
  TSNode node = UnmarshalNode(tree);
  if (node.id) {
    Nan::Maybe<uint32_t> byte = ByteCountFromJS(info[1]);
    if (byte.IsJust()) {
      MarshalNode(info, tree, ts_node_first_named_child_for_byte(node, byte.FromJust()));
      return;
    }
  }
  MarshalNullNode();
}

void Init(Local<Object> exports) {
  Local<Object> result = Nan::New<Object>();

  FunctionPair methods[] = {
    // ...
    {"firstNamedChildForIndex", FirstNamedChildForIndex},
    // ...
  };

  for (size_t i = 0; i < length_of_array(methods); i++) {
    Nan::Set(
      result,
      Nan::New(methods[i].name).ToLocalChecked(),
      Nan::GetFunction(Nan::New<FunctionTemplate>(methods[i].callback)).ToLocalChecked()
    );
  }

  module_exports.Reset(exports);
  setup_transfer_buffer(1);

  Nan::Set(exports, Nan::New("NodeMethods").ToLocalChecked(), result);
}
```

then it uses this method from JavaScript like this

```js
function marshalNode(node) {
  const {nodeTransferArray} = binding;
  for (let i = 0; i < NODE_FIELD_COUNT; i++) {
    nodeTransferArray[i] = node[i];
  }
}

class SyntaxNode {
  // ...

  firstNamedChildForIndex(index) {
    marshalNode(this);
    return unmarshalNode(NodeMethods.firstNamedChildForIndex(this.tree, index), this.tree);
  }
  // ...
}
```

This code works on Electron 12 and older, as well as Node.js 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 and 20. But on Electron 13+ it says there's no such method as `ArrayBuffer::New` or `ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore`:

```
node.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class v8::Local<class v8::ArrayBuffer> __cdecl v8::ArrayBuffer::New(class v8::Isolate *,class std::shared_ptr<class v8::BackingStore>)" (__imp_?New@ArrayBuffer@v8@@SA?AV?$Local@VArrayBuffer@v8@@@2@PEAVIsolate@2@V?$shared_ptr@VBackingStore@v8@@@std@@@Z) [D:\a\node-tree-sitter\node-tree-sitter\build\tree_sitter_runtime_binding.vcxproj]
node.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::unique_ptr<class v8::BackingStore,struct std::default_delete<class v8::BackingStore> > __cdecl v8::ArrayBuffer::NewBackingStore(void *,unsigned __int64,void (__cdecl*)(void *,unsigned __int64,void *),void *)" (__imp_?NewBackingStore@ArrayBuffer@v8@@SA?AV?$unique_ptr@VBackingStore@v8@@U?$default_delete@VBackingStore@v8@@@std@@@std@@PEAX_KP6AX010@Z0@Z) [D:\a\node-tree-sitter\node-tree-sitter\build\tree_sitter_runtime_binding.vcxproj]
```

How do I do this correctly on these versions of Electron?